# Azure Databricks analyze if the columns names are lower case, using islower() function

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

This is my logic on pyspark:

```
df2 = spark.sql(f" SELECT tbl_name, column_name, data_type, current_count FROM {database_name}.{tablename}")

query_df = spark.sql(f"SELECT tbl_name, COUNT(column_name) as `num_cols` FROM {database_name}.{tablename} GROUP BY tbl_name")            
                       
df_join = df2.join(query_df,['tbl_name'])
```

[image: Dataframe Result of previous logic]

Then I want to add to the Dataframe another column called 'column_case_lower' with the analyzes if the columns_names are lower case using islower() function.

I'm using this logic to do the analyzes:

```
df_join.withColumn("column_case_lower",
        when((col("column_name").islower()) == 'true'.otherwise('false'))
```

-- The error is: unexpected EOF while parsing

expecting something like this:

[image: expect result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`islower()` cant be applied on column type. Use the below code that uses `UDF` instead.

```
def checkCase(col_value):
    return col_value.islower()
    
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

checkUDF = udf(lambda z: checkCase(z),StringType())

from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when
df.withColumn("new_col", when(checkUDF(col('column_name')) == True,"True")
                                 .otherwise("False")).show()
```

[image]